# "Sync" two JS objects in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 2 JS objects, each is rendered as Tree in a webpage.

My issue is how to force a change on one of them while user applies a change to others.

My basic idea is *to "bind onChange" on each objects* obviously paying attention to not generate infinite loops.

In jQuery it seems almost difficult, I read something about "proxy" but I don't understand if it could help me on this topic.

I lastly thought to vue.js. I read that vue.js is very efficient [syncing js and dom objects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html) so a change between them is almost easy, maybe is possible to *sync* two js objects?

---

To be clearer, here more details:

I have something like this:

```
let obj1={key1:1, key2:[1,2,3]}; // defines arbitrary data obj
let obj2={};
$.extend(obj2,obj1); // defines obj2 as clone of obj1

// do "something magic" here
```

I would like to get the following:

```
obj1.key1=2; // => should automatically set  obj2.key1=2; under the hood
obj2.key2.push(4); // => should automatically set  obj1.key2=[1,2,3,4] under the hood
```

Is there any trick to bind two (identical, cloned) data objects so that any change made on one of them is reflected to the other one, as if the involved object keys "pointed" to the same data? Since objects are assigned "by reference" in javascript, this is doable if we define a third object "`obj_value`" and we assign it as value to the above objects as follows:

```
obj1.key=obj_value; // both obj1.key and obj2.key point to the same object
obj2.key=obj_value;
```

But I'd like something more general, directly binding one obj key to the other, in *pseudo-code*:

```
obj1.on('change',function(key,value)
{
  obj2.key=value;
})
```

Comment: You wont have to force if you use computed properties, can you provide more details on what these objects look like so that I can work it out on a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
watch: {
  objChangedByUser: function (value) {
    this.cloneOfobjChangedByUser = Object.assign({}, value);
  }
}
```

Or:

```
computed: {
  cloneOfObjChangedByUser: function () {
    return Object.assign({}, this.objChangedByUser);
  }
}
```